# Material Design md-Dialog and CKEDITOR

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, material-design, angular-template, angularjs-material

I have a question about **material design** and **ckeditor**.

My web project contains a dialog to compose a document with some metadatas and text content. For text content, I use `CKEDITOR` as a `richtexteditor`.

I designed it as follows,

1. Wrote a template that contains so many html tags and material design directives, named **"NewDocument.html"** (dialog contains
   tabs and tabs contains different types of data and template is about
   600 lines)
2. Put the button to show dialog
3. On the dialog's **onComplete** event, replace textarea with ckeditor.

Here is the code samples

```
$scope.createNewDocument = function (ev) {
            $myService.setEditorState(false);
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: $scope.NewDocumentDialogController,
                templateUrl: 'PageTemplates/ViewTemplates/NewDocument.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: false, 
                escapeToClose: false,
                onComplete: function () {
                    CKEDITOR.replace('documentEditor', $scope.editorConfig);

                    angular.element(document.querySelector(".sidenav-metadata")).css('height', window.innerHeight * 0.73 + 'px');
                    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".contentScrollable")).css('height', window.innerHeight * 0.5 + 'px');
                    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".searchableGrid")).css('height', window.innerHeight * 0.4 + 'px');

                    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (evt) {
                        $myService.setEditorState(true);
                    });
                },
                fullscreen: true
            });
        };
```

This function shows the dialog and here is the `editorConfig`:

```
$scope.editorConfig = {
            width: "100%",
            height: window.innerHeight * 0.53,
            enableTabKeyTools: true,
            removePlugins: 'elementspath',
            resize_enabled: false,
            language: "tr",
            extraAllowedContent: 'img[src,alt,width,height];*[id];table(*);*(*);*{*}',
            toolbar: [
                    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
                    { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellCheck'] },
                    { name: 'insert', items: ['OCUpload', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'] },
                    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
                    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent'] },
                    { name: 'justify', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
                    { name: 'justify2', items: ['BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'] },
                    { name: 'justify3', items: ['Font', 'FontSize'] },
                    { name: 'styles', items: ['appendDistribution', 'appendRelated', 'appendSignature', 'appendAttachment', 'appendCoordination', 'appendVacationRequest', 'appendDocumentDate'] }
            ]
        };
```

And here is the dialog controller;

```
$scope.NewDocumentDialogController = function ($scope, $mdDialog, $myService, $controller) {
            $scope.isReady = false;
            $scope.hide = function () {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };
            $scope.setCurrentTab = function (index) {
                $scope.currentTabIndex = index;
            };
            $scope.getCurrentTab = function () {
                return $scope.currentTabIndex;
            };
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $myService.getEditorState();
            }, function (newVal) {
                $scope.isReady = newVal;
            });
        };
```

I just posted some code parts, because I couldn't find any support for `ckeditor` in **plunker** and **codepen**.

My problem is, the dialog appears with a textarea that doesn't replace with ckeditor. And after a few seconds, the textarea replace with ckeditor.

I tried contentElement for preRendering dialog and onShowing event, but that does not work for me.

For now, as a temporary solution, I put a loading indicator to dialog and the loading indicator appears while `textarea` is replacing with `ckeditor`. But this solution doesn't make sense for me. Is there any suggestion, or any different solution for this. Thanks for helps.